# Using Java check xml file contains SOAP Message or XSD content or WSDL content

Tags: java, xml, regex, xsd, wsdl

With the help of java, how can we check weather passed file contains pure SOAP Message or it is an XSD or it is a WSDL.

Need strong regular expression to check this.

Suppose we read an file(FileType is .txt) and 
1. If the passed file contains SOAPMessage inside it without another extra tag. How to handle this use case.
2. If the passed file contains XSD then how to handle this use case
3.  If the passed file contains WSDL then how to handle this use case

Comment: Find three decent parsers: one for SOAP, one for XSD and one for WSDL, then pass them the files. The reponse of the parsers will tell you what kind of file you have...

Comment: @Alex Is there any specific Open Source API available that do something like as you mentioned SOAP Parser only parse if file has SOAP Message and report error if that parser found anything other then SOAP Message & XSD parser only parse XSD and report that if it found any other tags & WSDL parse only parse WSDL and report that if it found any other tags.

Comment: @Alex Still waiting for your reply